# Cannot invoke findViewById(int) on the primitive type int

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to get selected value from spinner in android app.

I tried like following as my spinner is in dialog popup

```
final Spinner problems = (Spinner) layout.input_dialog.findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));
              problems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                 @Override
                 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view1, int pos, long id)
                 {
                     spin_problem_val = adapter.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                 }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

statement `final Spinner problems = (Spinner) layout.input_dialog.findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));` gives me error `Cannot invoke findViewById(int) on the primitive type int`

why so ?

if I tried like this `final Spinner problems = (Spinner) findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));`

I will get `NullPointerException`

`input_dialog` is my `input_dialog.xml` dialog popup where my spinner is

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_problems"
        android:entries="@array/problems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
         />
```

Comment: post the entire class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you run this code *after* the layout has been set.
The error you have typically occurs when you try to access a View before you have loaded the layout.

Please check that this code is running *after* your `onCreateView` function has set the layout.

Comment: thanks I able to resolve it by following code 
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
  View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
 final Spinner problems = (Spinner) promptView.findViewById((R.id.spinner_problems));
   spin_problem_val = problems.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Yes - the `LayoutInflater` will load the selected layout, allowing you to find specific views with the `findViewById(int)` method.

Answer (score 1):

`layout.input_dialog` is an `int` field in your generated `R.java`. You cannot invoke methods on primitive types such as `int`, you need an object for that.

Since you've attempting to find the view from a dialog, call `findViewById()` in your `Dialog` object. To get specific help with that, please post more code.